# jQuery ticker tape script partially running

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jsnewsticker plugin (http://jsfiddle.net/stevenchu/ezEtK/) which uses `<li>` to display an item at a time.

The code below works if my `<li>` items are hard-coded into the HTML. But it doesn't work if I have to dynamically create the `<li>` items from an RSS feed which my script below does

The final HTML page has the `<li>` items but the JS isn't scrolling through them. I'm not getting any errors in the console. The JS is appending ticker-active class to my `<ul>` though.

Could this be a sequential issue - perhaps the JS script is firing before the list of `<li>` items has been fully rendered?  If possible, is there a way I can test this theory?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jsnewsticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://example.com/feed', function (data) {
        var count = 0;
        $(data).find("item").each(function () {
            var newsfeed = $(this);     
            var newstitle = newsfeed.find("title").text();
            var newslink = newsfeed.find("link").text();

            var newslist = '';
            if (count < 3) {
                newslist += '<li class="newsitem">'
                + '<a href="'
                + newslink
                + '">Latest: '
                + newstitle
                + '</a>'
                + '</li>';
                count++;
            }

            $(".latestnews").append(newslist);
        });

    });

    $('.ticker').Ticker();
});
</script>
```

The HTML taken from browser source:

```
<ul class="latestnews ticker ticker-active">
    <li class="newsitem"><a href="http://example.com">Example</a></li>
    <li class="newsitem"><a href="http://example.com">Example</a></li>
    <li class="newsitem"><a href="http://example.com">Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your own question earlier. Yes, you are calling ticker before the `async` Ajax `get` call has completed, so it fires up the `ticker` against an empty list.

You need to call it inside the `get`. e.g. something like:

```
<script src="/js/jsnewsticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('http://example.com/feed', function (data) {
        var count = 0;
        $(data).find("item").each(function () {
            var newsfeed = $(this);     
            var newstitle = newsfeed.find("title").text();
            var newslink = newsfeed.find("link").text();

            var newslist = '';
            if (count < 3) {
                newslist += '<li class="newsitem">'
                + '<a href="'
                + newslink
                + '">Latest: '
                + newstitle
                + '</a>'
                + '</li>';
                count++;
            }

            $(".latestnews").append(newslist);
        });
        $('.ticker').Ticker();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected the issue but didn't know how to resolve it. Your solution has worked but I'm unsure why it worked. Your solution calls the ticker function within the loop? Whereas my logic was to let the loop finish (thus finish constructing the <li>) and then run the ticker function.

Comment: Sorry that should be outside the loop... it only worked because it started the ticker after every iteration. I have adjusted the code :)